# Como fechar um JInternalFrame ao abrir outro?

Tags: java, jinternalframe

Oi pessoal estou desenvolvendo um projeto pro meu curso, e quando clico no menu para abrir um novo `JInternalFrame`, o mesmo abre "abaixo" do outro já aberto.
 Gostaria de saber como faço para abri-lo "em cima" do ja aberto?
segue o código:

```
public class Inicial extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conexao = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Cadastro cadastro = new Cadastro();
Relatorio relatorio = new Relatorio();
EditarExcluir editarExcluir = new EditarExcluir();

public Inicial() {
    initComponents();
    conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();
    System.out.println(conexao);
}
private void menuCadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              


    cadastro.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(cadastro);


}                                             

private void menuRelatorioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    relatorio.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(relatorio);

}                                             

private void menuEditarExcluirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    editarExcluir.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(editarExcluir);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deixe para instancia-los dentro da ação do botão, quem sabe isso ajude.
Lembrando que por se tratar de um JInternalFrame pode-se usar o `.show`

Ex:

```java
    private void menuRelatorioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
         Relatorio relatorio = new Relatorio();
         desktop.add(relatorio);
         relatorio.show();

    }
```